# how to mock data with extension methods?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I want test this method. Not exactly this because it does not make sense to test this, but this is simple version of what I need.

```
public bool Test()
{
    var authenticationScheme = Context.GetCurrentAuthenticationScheme();
    return authenticationScheme == "google";
}
```

GetCurrentAuthenticationScheme is extension method.

```
public static string GetCurrentAuthenticationScheme(this HttpContext context)
{

    var protector = context.ApplicationServices
                           .GetDataProtector(nameof(CookieStateHandlerExtensions));
    return protector.Unprotect(context.Request
                                      .Cookies[CURRENTAUTHENTICATIONSCHEMECOOKIE]
                                      .FirstOrDefault());
}
```

**GetDataProtector** is also extension method from  "Microsoft.AspNet.DataProtection" 
**Unprotect** is extension method from same namespace.

My question is how to mock this(using Moq) so that GetCurrentAuthenticationScheme() return string I want?

Comment: Yes, but does not help me in my case. Because I still don't know how to write test. How to return what I want from GetCurrentAuthenticationScheme?

Comment: If you use `HttpContext.Current`, then you can initialize it manually in your test method... BTW it looks like a code which you'd better test through as integration test instead of UT...